# Почему метод всегда возвращает 0

Tags: java, android, firebase

Есть метод, но почему то он всегда возвращает 0, а список заполняется в чем проблема?

```
public List<CategoryList> getTodayItems() {
    categoriesList = new ArrayList<>();

    String userID = user.getUid();
    // Write a message to the database
    myRef = fbDatabase.getReference(userID);
    myRef.keepSynced(true);

    myRef.child(DBHelper.TABLE_OPERATIONS).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            categoriesList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                CategoryList post = postSnapshot.getValue(CategoryList.class);
                categoriesList.add(post);
            }
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "categoriesList size after = " + categoriesList.size());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "categoriesList size inReturn = " + categoriesList.size());

    return categoriesList;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Вы запускаете метод.
2. Он запускает асинхронную операцию по получению данных из FireBase.
3. Эти данные могут прийти быстро, очень не быстро или вообще не прийти.
4. Не дожидаясь того что произойдёт в п.3 вы возвращаете пустой список данных

Так как вы планируете написать у вас не получится из-за того, что действия в разных потоках происходят. Вам надо перестроить логику так, чтобы нигде не было нужды синхронно получать данные, получаемые асинхронно.

---

Я бы это сделал с помощью RxJava как-то так:

```
Observable.<List<CategoryList>>create(subscriber -> {
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    firebaseDatabase.getReference()
            .child(DBHelper.TABLE_OPERATIONS)
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   List<CategoryList> categoriesList = new ArrayList<>();
                   for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                       CategoryList post = postSnapshot.getValue(CategoryList.class);
                       categoriesList.add(post);
                    }
                    subscriber.onNext(categoriesList);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    subscriber.onError(databaseError.toException());
                }
            });
})
.subscribe(
    data -> {//вот обновлённые данные из Firebase},
    e -> {//какая-то огибка произошла}
);
```

Comment: а как тогда мне получить эти данные после получения из Firebase?

Comment: @java,  обновил ответ

Comment: а что нужно импортировать? Что-то ни один вариант импорта не помог, скрин добавил, обновил вопрос

Comment: @java, чтобы приведённый мной код работал нужны 3 либы - RxJava, RxAndroid и Retrolambda. Первые 2 надо до 2 версии брать, если вы не хотите переписывать приведённый код из-за изменений в именах методов 2 версии RxJava

Comment: я добавил все либы с офф репозиториев, но ничего не заработало почему - то, я не совсем разбираюсь в лямба выражениях, но в конце надо было что-то типо этого сделать `subscribe(
                        data -> categoriesList = data,
                        e -> e.printStackTrace());` ?

Comment: Например да. Но мой пример не про то как изменить ваш код что бы он работал. Синхронно вернуть данные из метода вы никак совсем всё равно не сможете. Вам надо переписывать архитектурно процесс работы с данными. Написать метод, возвращаюший асинхронные данные синхронно просто невозможно.

Comment: спасибо, буду думать дальше что делать